# SQL query slow performance 'LIKE CNTR%04052021%

Tags: sql, azure, query-optimization

we have a database that is growing every day. roughly 40M records as of today.

This table/database is located in Azure.

The table has a primary key 'ClassifierID', and the query is running on this primary key.

The primary key is in the format of ID + timestamp (mmddyyy HHMMSS), for example 'CNTR00220200 04052021 073000'

Here is the query to get all the IDs by date

```
 **Select distinct ScanID
 From ClassifierResults
 Where ClassifierID LIKE 'CNTR%04052020%**
```

Very simple and straightforward, but it sometimes takes over a min to complete. Do you have any suggestion how we can optimize the query? Thanks much.

Comment: That is a poor candidate for a primary key - keys should be as narrow as possible and also be atomic - ie - not multiple distinct properties munged together.

Comment: The poor performance is likely because with every value starting 'CNTR' and you doing a like 'CNTR%', the selectivity is zero so a scan wil have to be performed - *every* row is like CNTR?

Comment: Agreed. Primary Key was not designed properly. Did not anticipate the data to grow to this scale.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing here would be to fix your design so that a) you are not storing the ID and timestamp in the same text field, and b) you are storing the timestamp in a proper date/timestamp column.  Using your single point of data, I would suggest the following table design:

```
ID           | timestamp
CNTR00220200 | timestamp '2021-04-05 07:30:00'
```

Then, create an index on `(ID, timestamp)`, and use this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ID LIKE 'CNTR%' AND
      timestamp >= '2021-04-05' AND timestamp < '2021-04-06';
```

The above query searches for records having an `ID` starting with `CNTR` and falling exactly on the date `2021-04-05`.  Your SQL database should be able to use the composite index I suggested above on this query.

Comment: Agreed. The table should be designed better. Before we add another column to it, is there any room to optimize the query? probably not based on what you said, correct?

Comment: `LIKE 'CNTR%04052020%'` is a real performance killer because it can't be indexed AFAIK.  I suggest changing your design if at all possible, because your problem is only going to get much worse as the table continues growing.  Maybe someone else give you a temporary workaround.

Comment: Really appreciate your thought

Comment: Create a view or a computed column to pull out just the date part from the text column; can then create an index on it and use to filter rows instead.

Comment: when you create an index on ID and Time together, do you need to update the index regularly? Does the database handle this update itself?

Comment: The index needs to be updated every time the data changes.